# How to walk through and parse folder of json files then output to single file

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I have a folder of json files that I want to parse for specific key,value pairs. Then append those pairs to a dictionary and then output that dictionary (as rows of json) to a new json file. I currently am unable to get the files in my folder to parse, much less funnel the parsed data to the dictionary for printing. Here is my code:

```
import json, os

FbDict=[]

topdir=os.getcwd() 

def main():        

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):            
        for f in files:                        
            if f.lower().endswith((".json")):                    
                json_data = open(f, 'r+').read().decode("utf-8")
                jdata = json.loads(json_data)   
                fname=f.split(".json")[0]
                for k, v in jdata.items(): 
                    if isinstance(v, dict):                                                                
                        try:
                            dataFormat = {"created_at":v['data'][0]['created_time'],"user":v['data'][0]['from']['id'],
                                               "id":v['data'][0]['id'],"name":v['data'][0]['from']['name'],"text":v['data'][0]['message']}                                        
                                FbDict.append(json.dumps(dataFormat, separators=(',', ':')))                                                                            
                        except KeyError:
                            continue                            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    with open ('fbFile', 'w') as f:
        f.write(FbDict)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Does it produce errors? Does it run but produce erroneous output?

Comment: @larsks oh yeah, that. It's giving me [errno 2] - no such file or directory and listing a file that isn't in the folder but was open in notepad before. I don't understand how this code is sorting through other files that aren't part of the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @rmunn & @Rob for the help, Here's the update:

```
import json, os

FbDict=[]

def main():        

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):            
        for f in files:                        
            if f.lower().endswith((".json")):                    
                f = os.path.join(root, f)
                with open(f, 'r') as f: json_data=f.read().decode("utf-8")
                jdata = json.loads(json_data)                       
                for k, v in jdata.items(): 
                    if isinstance(v, dict):                                                                
                        try:
                            dataFormat = {"created_at":v['data'][0]['created_time'],"user":v['data'][0]['from']['id'],
                                           "id":v['data'][0]['id'],"name":v['data'][0]['from']['name'],"text":v['data'][0]['message']}                                        
                            if dataFormat no in FbDict:
                                FbDict.append(json.dumps(dataFormat, separators=(',',':')))                          
                            else:
                                continue              
                        except KeyError:
                            continue
                f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    with open ('fbFile.json', 'w') as f_out:
        for line in fbDict:
             f_out.write(line+'\n')
        f_out.close()
```

Comment: Good job finding your own answer, and posting it. You are allowed to accept your own answer, as well, if it is correct.  Two criticisms: 1) You don't need `'r+'`, `'r'` would be more appropriate, 2) you don't close the file you open. Try `with open(f,'r') as f: json_data = f.read().decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks for the help! I'll add your suggestions in an update. How do i add functionality to go through subfolders?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the part from the Python documentation that you're missing:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

> Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with *top*) to a file or directory in *dirpath*, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.

Right now you're just iterating on `files`, which is the bare filenames without any path information. Add the path information and you should stop getting those "file not found" errors.

Comment: that makes sense, I'm just confused about where to add it?

Comment: @user2338089 - do you want to search only the top-level files, or search all json files, recursing through all subdirectories?

Comment: @Robᵩ the further the better, so all subdirectories would be helpful